# Process array returned by active x control(VB) in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, com, activex, activexobject

I am developing an ActiveX control for IE  which is invoked through javascript. The ActiveX control is developed in visual basic and it has an array of strings. How will I use this array of strings in javascript.

Eg :-

```
var a = new Array()
a = objActiveX.GetArray(); // call to active x returns array of string, how will I loop through this in javascript.
```

The above line does not work.
I want to loop through each string in javascript.

Advise.

Comment: need some more info. what "doesn't work"? what do you get with 'alert("a:" + a);"?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, arrays returned from COM/OLE/ActiveX components are `SAFEARRAY`s. There's a special object in JScript called `VBArray` that adapts between the two.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2006/07/04/howto-convert-between-jscript-array-and-vb-safe-array.aspx for a good example of going back and forth between JavaScript arrays and `SAFEARRAY`s.

More detailed info on `VBArray` here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s0fw3t2(VS.80).aspx

Note that this is part of JScript -- I'm not 100% sure that IEs default scripting runtime is JScript, but I think so.

Answer (score 1):

This function will convert a multi-dimensional VB safe-array into a multi-dimensional javascript array.

[Try it out](http://dumpsite.com/forum/index.php?topic=63.0), Let me know if you can break it.